# There is any way to get status change in real time using AJAX jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to  get a status from database using jQuery AJAX. For this status I have 3 options, if the status is pending I want to keep loading the request, if I go to database and change this status to success or error, the loading request will interrupt and return the status(error and success status).

**jQuery Code**

```
$.ajax({
type:'get',
url:getStatus.php?record_id=50,
success: function(e){
  console.log(e)
} 
});
```

**PHP Code - getStatus.php**

```
<?php 

require_once (class/class.php');

$stat = new Stat();

$record_id= $_GET['record_id'];

$status = $stat->getStatus($record_id);

echo $status;
```

**PHP Code - geStatus() Class Method**

```
  public function getStatus($record_id){
     
    $query = "  SELECT `status` from records "; 
    $query.= " WHERE `record_id`='{$record_id}' ";

    /* Get query response */
    $response = $this->QueryKey($query);

    
    if($response==true){

        $output['success']=$response[0];
    }
    
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: describe the problem in more detail. At the moment you are returning the status from the database to the browser

Comment: "I want" isn't a question. It's unclear what specific problem you're having or what you want from us. Presumably you need to write some code in your `success` function to read the response from the server, and then do whatever is needed based on that response. Where are you stuck? have you tried anything? See also [ask] for advice on asking a useful question here.

Comment: If you want to keep monitoring the status, you'll need to keep making repeated AJAX requests to the server (e.g. you could set an interval in JS to do that regularly). You cannot "keep loading the request" as you described it, because your JS code does not see the response until the request has already finished. (And if you try to do that in PHP, it will likely just result in the request timing out instead, and/or blocking your server resources while it loops and polls the database).

Comment: P.S. If you're serious about doing this at scale, you should be looking at WebSockets rather than AJAX, to avoid performance problems.

Comment: First of all, the english is not my main language, the second my question is how to make ajax request that keep loading the request until the status is pending, if this status change to success or error this request will stop loading.

Comment: `First of all, the english is not my main language`...ok, but I don't think "I want" is considered to be a question in _any_ language.

Comment: `make ajax request that keep loading the request`...I already told you how to do this - set an interval in JavaScript. It looks like the answer below gave an example of this, so hopefully your problem is solved anyway.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I have take also your answer in consideration, but other guy has posted as solution below and I have checked as solved, also other solution that you have gave to me using websocket I think will worked better than setInterval, but I never used websocket before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, You call ajax code in every 5 sec duration and get the status...

```
function checkStatusRealTime(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:getStatus.php?record_id=50,
        success: function(e){
            if(status == 'pending'){
                // code...
            }else if(status == 'success'){
                clearInterval(realTimeCheck);
            }else{

            }
        } 
    });
}
let realTimeCheck = setInterval(checkStatusRealTime,5000); //call every 5sec
```